# Efficient way to create an ipv6 range when a subnet value is given

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to process an ipv6 range like FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329/120 and store the addresses in the range in a table using *PL/SQL* block.

In my current implementation I am converting the address into binary, iterating between minimum and maximum addresses in a while loop and inserting them in a table.

It works fine for smaller ranges, but need an efficient way to handle large ranges (something on the lines of bulk insert using fetch)

```
 while ipv6_counter_iterator <= ipv6_counter_max
          loop
        ipv6_value_intermediate := nvl(lpad(dec2bin(ipv6_counter_iterator),
                                            ipv6_counter,
                                            '0'),
                                       '');
        ipv6_binary_value       := substr(ipv6_addr, 1, ipv6_range) ||
                                   ipv6_value_intermediate;
        ipv6_address_value      := Binary_to_ipv6(ipv6_binary_value);
        ipv6_counter_iterator   := ipv6_counter_iterator + 1;
        insert into sdb_ip_range_values
          (ip_address, session_id)
        values
          (ipv6_address_value, session);
      end loop;
    END IF;
```

Comment: You really should rethink what you are doing. Saving the start and end of the range should be enough and a give you probably better performance than saving all address.

Comment: yes , but in my project i have to connect to these address and process some information , so it is essential for me to store all the addresses in the range in a table

Answer (score 0):

you should think about using a stored procedure that checks if a given ipv6 address is in the block.

there are two ways for doing so:

- make the ipv6 address and the range binary and build a subnet mask for it. then compare a binary AND of the ipv6 address and the range. it should be the same.
- the other way would be a test if the address is bigger or equal to the starting address AND lesser or equal to the end address.